# "Host 'xxxx is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server" when installing Ranger DBs via Ambari

Tags: ambari, apache-ranger

Trying to install an HDP cluster on 3 centos7 nodes (for testing / evaluation purposes) and am encountering errors at the part when am asked to configure DBs for Ranger and Ranger KMS.

[image]

When running the connection tests for automated DB and DB user setup by Ambari, seeing errors indicating that nodes are not able to connect.

[image]

```sh
2019-07-18 16:22:02,448 - Check db_connection_check was unsuccessful. Exit code: 1. Message: ERROR: Unable to connect to the DB. Please check DB connection properties. java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host 'HW02.co.local' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server" 
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/custom_actions/scripts/check_host.py", line 546, in <module>    CheckHost().execute()  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 352, in execute    method(env)  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/custom_actions/scripts/check_host.py", line 207, in actionexecute    raise Fail(error_message) resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Check db_connection_check was unsuccessful. Exit code: 1. Message: ERROR: Unable to connect to the DB. Please check DB connection properties. java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host 'HW02.co.local' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
```

I have a freshly installed MySQL server on a datanode and can run

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost`
```

but getting errors for

```
mysql -u root -p -h <some remote cluster node>`
```

throws

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '' (111)

The mysql confing file looks to be binding to all interfaces...

```sh
[root@HW03 ~]# cat /etc/my.cnf

# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

[mysqld]
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
bind-address=0.0.0.0

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

so not sure what the problem could be.

Not very experienced with MySQL or DBA. Any debugging suggestions or fixes for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following an answer from the Hortonworks [community forums](http://community.hortonworks.com/answers/249380/view.html) is what ultimately allowed the Ambari connection test to pass:

On the mysql server, running...

```sh
[root@HW03 ~]# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 51
Server version: 5.6.44 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use mysql;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

mysql> use mysql;
Database changed
mysql>
mysql> CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<root's password, THIS IS NOT LITERAL>';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
```

and now can see...
[image]

Though, still does not solve the problem of not being able to access mysql from the other remote hosts, ie. still getting errors

```
mysql -u root -p -h <some remote cluster node>`
```

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '' (111)